# Getting compile error in table-based view in iOS

Tags: xcode

I am getting a compile error in my RootViewController.m file. Here is the code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
```

@implementation RootViewController

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark View lifecycle

/*
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

}
*/

/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
 */

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

[cell.textLabelSetText@"Hello World!"];

return cell;
```

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source.
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
}
```

}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  /*
   <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
   // ...
   // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
   [detailViewController release];
   */
  }

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

  // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }
- (void)viewDidUnload {
  // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
  // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
  }
- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
  }

@end

The problem part is:

[cell.textLabelSetText@"Hello World!"];

I get an error which reads: Request for member textLabelSetText in something not a structure or a union

and

Expected ':' before OBJC_STRING token

Can you tell me what's wrong? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the colon `:`

```
[cell.textLabelSetText:@"Hello World!"];
```

But that should actually be

```
[cell.textLabel setText:@"Hello World!"];
```

...or in the new dot notation

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello World!";
```